# How to reference Parameters passed to Partial view in a separate javascript file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a Partial view in a view which take in parameters like this:

```
 @Html.Partial("_MarkdownEditor", new { id = "editorsection" })
 @Html.Partial("_MarkdownEditor", new { id = "fieldcomments" })
```

In the Partial view i am trying to insert a Markdown editor according to value passed in as parameters like this:

```
<div id="@ViewData.Eval("id")"> </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var @ViewData.Eval("id") = new tui.Editor({
el: document.querySelector('#@ViewData.Eval("id")')})
</script>
```

It creates a new instance of Markdown editor based on parameter passed to the partial view.

In the source code of the tui.Editor i have a Ajax call to a controller something like this..

```
$.ajax({
              url: 'Home/Index',
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'text',      
              data: { capture: reader.result },
              success: function (data) {
                      editor.importManager.eventManager.emit('command', 'AddImage', {
                      imageUrl: data,
                      altText: 'image'
                  });
              },
```

Here the problem is with this line..

```
editor.importManager.eventManager.emit('command', 'AddImage)
```

Here in the place of editor i need to reference the parameters passed to Partial view..it should be like this:

```
editorsection.importManager.eventManager.emit('command', 'AddImage)
fieldcomments.importManager.eventManager.emit('command', 'AddImage)
```

It should be done dynamically i have tried something like..

```
{@ViewData.Eval("id")}.importManager.eventManager.emit('command', 'AddImage)
```

But this doesn't work like this? How can i reference the Parameters passed to Partial view in a separate javascript file??

Comment: Store value in Layout as js variable , easy you can use it. Keep in mind make sure hierarchy of file.

Comment: @Asif Raza I didn&#39;t get that.. could you please elaborate!! With example.